# Jenkins: pull request builder comment posting to github after downstream finished

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pull-request

Is there any possible way to suspend sending comment in pull request after all downstream job finished?

When the pull request triggered, a job packages that pull request and artifact this packages. On post-build action the job also trigger other 4 jobs.Those triggered jobs uses the artifact with copy artifact plugins. I wanted that comment notification only sent when the downstream job finished building. Is that possible?